# How to get count of lines per current second?

Tags: awk, scripting

I do tcpdump of voip traffic using this command:

```
tcpdump -nn  port 5060  -i eth0 | grep 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.5060: SIP: SIP/2.0 5'
```

and got something like that:

```
11:10:03.600493 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.5060 > yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.5060: SIP: SIP/2.0 500 Server Internal Error
11:10:03.610092 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.5060 > yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.5060: SIP: SIP/2.0 500 Server Internal Error
11:10:03.860551 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.5060 > yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.5060: SIP: SIP/2.0 500 Server Internal Error
11:10:04.190145 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.5060 > yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.5060: SIP: SIP/2.0 504 Server Time-out
11:10:04.510174 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.5060 > yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.5060: SIP: SIP/2.0 500 Server Internal Error
11:10:04.870164 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.5060 > yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.5060: SIP: SIP/2.0 500 Server Internal Error
11:10:06.010196 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.5060 > yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.5060: SIP: SIP/2.0 500 Server Internal Error
11:10:07.039787 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.5060 > yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.5060: SIP: SIP/2.0 503 Service Unavailable
11:10:07.330243 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.5060 > yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.5060: SIP: SIP/2.0 500 Server Internal Error
11:10:08.520721 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.5060 > yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.5060: SIP: SIP/2.0 500 Server Internal Error
11:10:08.720207 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.5060 > yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.5060: SIP: SIP/2.0 503 Service Unavailable
```

How to get in realtime a count of such lines for current second? i.e if now is 11:10:08 i would get 2 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realtime solution, as asked in original post.

Save following code as script and make it executable:

```
#!/bin/bash

current_sec=0
while read line
do
    prev_sec=$current_sec
    current_sec=${line:0:8}
    if [ "$current_sec" == "$prev_sec" ]
    then
        line_count=$((line_count+1))
    else
        echo $prev_sec /// $line_count
        line_count=1
    fi
done
```

Then run:

```
tcpdump -nn  port 5060  -i eth0 | grep 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.5060: SIP: SIP/2.0 5' | saved_script.sh
```

This will print in realtime:

```
13:29:50 /// 0
13:29:51 /// 4
13:29:52 /// 9
13:29:54 /// 2
```

I didn't test this code enough, there may be bugs, but you can test it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I take the date of last log and then i grep for it, adding in watch i believe is what you need.

somefile - is your log file

```
grep $(tail -1 somefile | awk -F . '{print $1}') somefile

watch -n1 "grep $(tail -1 somefile | awk -F . '{print $1}') somefile"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file is sorted:

```
grep -oP "^[0-2][0-9]:[0-2][0-9]:[0-2][0-9]" inputfile | uniq -c
```

Will return the number of entrys for each whole second.

```
      3 11:10:03
      3 11:10:04
      1 11:10:06
      2 11:10:07
      2 11:10:08
```